# Result of BsonDocument.ToJson fails when used in JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, .net, json, mongodb, bson

I'm retrieving data from MongoDB and then sending it to client:

```
var bsonDocument = ... retrieve from database ...
var dto = new Dto { MyBson = bsonDocument.ToJson() };
```

On the client I'm trying to parse `MyBson` property using `JSON.parse`.

I'm getting the following error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token N`. I guess this is because one of the properties looks like this:

```
{ ..., "SomeIntProp" : NumberLong(70) }
```

JavaScript parser simply doesn't understand Bson data type: `NumberLong`.

How should I convert BsonDocument to JSON so that the output would omit `NumberLong`?

Comment: Here is a link which shows how its done in php: https://github.com/bobthecow/genghis/blob/master/src/php/Genghis/Json.php. I did the same thing in JS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to solve this, I worked out a solution by writing my own parsing function which understands the MongoDB BSON types and does the conversion. The native JSON.parse only understands the types used by the JavaScript. Here is my version: 
https://gist.github.com/Hrish2006/8270187 
You probably will not need the html snippets in the code.